# SQL Server: encoding of string constants in SQL

Tags: sql-server, unicode, internationalization, collation

I have a problem with encoding of string constants in queries to NVARCHAR field in SQL Server v12.0.2. I need to use national characters (all in the same single code page e.g. cyrillic WIN1251) in queries without N prefix.

Is it possible?

Example:

```
1. CREATE TABLE TEST (VALUE NVARCHAR(100) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS);
2. INSERT INTO TEST VALUES (N'привет мир');
3. INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('привет мир');
4. SELECT * FROM TEST;
```

This will return two rows:

```
 | привет мир |
 | ?????? ??? |
```

So the first insert works correctly, I expect the second to do the same because TEST.VALUE column collated in Cyrillic_General_CI_AS. But it looks like national characters ignores field collation and use code page from somewhere else.

I realize that in this case I won't be able to use characters from more than one code page and languages that doesn't fit 1-byte encoding, but that is fine for me. Other option is to modify all queries to use N prefix before string constants, but it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the **database**, not the table you're inserting into (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) for details)

So either you should change database collation to Cyrillic_General_CI_AS, or find all the string constants and insert N prefix.

Comment: I also tried to set database encoding to Cyrillic_General_CI_AS (beacuse in some articles, for example, [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/239530/you-must-precede-all-unicode-strings-with-a-prefix-n-when-you-deal-with-unicode-string-constants-in-sql-server) specified that national characters using DB default code page when transcoding, but it doesn't help

Comment: @vbe It looks kinda strange. All of my DBs has exactly Cyrillic_General_CI_AS collation, and selecting some string constant with cyryllic characters in it and without N prefix works just fine. Well. your last option is to change server default collation, I suppose.

Comment: Example script (it doesn't work!):
`CREATE DATABASE TEST COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS;

CREATE TABLE TEST.dbo.TEST (
    VALUE NVARCHAR(10) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
);

INSERT INTO TEST.dbo.TEST VALUES ('привет мир');
SELECT * FROM TEST.dbo.TEST;`

Comment: Ok, I guess setting database collation should work, probably issue somwhere else. Thanks, Andy.

Comment: Also could you verify that example code from my comment above is working for you?

Comment: @vbe I've just tested your code sample. Yes, it is working and last select outputs correct cyrillic characters. Can't guess what's wrong at your side... Try to change server default collation as I've suggested above (my server has Cyrillic_General_CI_AS as server collation)